# How to add cols on top of image in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Please i am new to bootstrap. Recently lean the grids etc. I am trying to add controls like a table or on top of an image exactly like the search and the testimonial one [here](http://www.stjobs.sg/) . Just from the example, i dont want by whole site on top the image. Just one row.

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
<div class='row' style='position:absolute; z-index=-1'>
   <img src='images/banner.jpg'  alt='Blast off with Bootstrap' />
</div>


 <!-- My other controls goes here, example my table etc. -->
</div>

<div class='container'>

 <!-- I dont like what ever is in this container to display on top the image above.-->
</div>
```

When i run my code , everything displays on the image including the second container. Please how do i archive that? Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check out this code i had provided the working example

```
<div class='container-fluid'>
<div class='row banner'>
   <img src='http://images.visitcanberra.com.au/images/canberra_hero_image.jpg'  alt='Blast off with Bootstrap' />
    <div class="table-block">        
         <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Firstname</th>
            <th>Lastname</th>
            <th>Savings</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Peter</td>
            <td>Griffin</td>
            <td>$100</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Lois</td>
            <td>Griffin</td>
            <td>$150</td>
          </tr>
        </table>        
    </div>
</div>
 <!-- My other controls goes here, example my table etc. -->
</div>

<div class='container'>

 <!-- I dont like what ever is in this container to display on top the image above.-->
</div>
```

CSS code :

```
 img{
        width:100%;
        height:200px;
    }
    table, td, th {
        border: 1px solid #111;
    }

    table {
        width: 400px;
    }
    .table-block{
        position:absolute;
        top:25px;
        left:25px;
    }
    .banner{position:relative;}
```

[working example](http://jsfiddle.net/vasanthanvas/hkLurLac/1/)

Comment: @brickleberry  is this ur expecting ?

Comment: that's my Expectation sir. Would try and put this to work. Thanks for the help.

Comment: just wondering pls. Do you know the color code of the blue section? Or better the hex code for the 'Add Comment' and 'Answer Your Question' on this page (i.e SO). Have been trying to figure out .

Comment: @brickleberry  u need to add link ? or u expecting this  `background-color: #009afd;`

Comment: Thank you man. i think its fine now. I needed the hex and you provided. It works now.